# My RHEEM Gas hot water tank keeps shutting Off with code 2

Tags: water, water-heater, plumbing-fixture, hot-water, bathroom-fixtures

The Plumber said it's the gas valve assy. So I ordered a gas valve. After installing, the problem still exist. The plumber even broke the sight glass to "let more air in". After breaking the glass with the same problem, now he said I need a new tank. The tank is only 11months old purchased from my local Home Depot. Now, I decided to repair it myself. I tested the Thermopile and its very slow in producing DC mv. It took almost a minute to reach over 500mv using a propane torch. I ordered a Thermopile so waiting for the part. Now, when I removed the burner, I noticed that the there's no TRD vial at the combustion chamber. Will this cause my hot water tank to ignite initially then when the burner fires, it will go out after a few seconds?

Comment: 11 months. What's the warranty?

Comment: Sounds like you need a new plumber, for one thing.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Should a plumber even be looking at the gas section of a hot water tank?  Would imagine you should have a gas technician for gas work if there is a problem.

Comment: Depends - in some areas they overlap so gas is done by a plumber (both involve pipes.) In other areas they are strictly separated, or require dual licensing. Depends on the rules in the LAHJ.

Comment: My HVAC guy also does gas piping, @crip659, so it's not unheard of. Now, in the case of our OP, maybe he should... :)

Comment: Most of the plumbers I work with do gas, steam and regular pipe work, but I know some areas are stricter I also work on furnaces or used to but I have HVAC licenses.